# Chinese text feature extraction using n-gram

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, text-mining

I am trying to use bigram model to do Chinese text feature extraction. It's easy to get feature words in a document. But I have no idea about converting feature words to feature vector. Anyone have a good idea? 
By the way, In my opinion, words in title are much important than words in content. What can I deal with the words in title when using n-gram model?